# Which is right “Did or have”?

Tags: difference

I have heard in “Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire” that Harry says “I did not do it” when Ron asks whether he put his name?

Why doesn’t he say “I have not done it” instead of “did”?

Comment: I'm not sure of the context (he put his name where?), but he might have said "I haven't done it" about something he was expected to do, like his homework. Presumably this relates to something unexpected, so "I did not do it" implies "It must have been somebody else".

Comment: Both are grammatically possible.  We need more context. Please give a link to the text, or copy and paste enough of it, so that we can see what was happening before he said this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Did not* is *past tense*, it's talking about a time or event in the past, which has ended. *Have not* is *present perfect*, and it has a sense of "up to now", "so far" etc.

*I did not do it* sounds like he had an opportunity to put in his name, but he didn't, and that opportunity ended. He can't do it now, he missed his chance!

*I have not done it* sounds like he hasn't done it *yet*, but he still could if he wanted to. The competition (I think?) is still open, and he can still put his name in.

So the difference is that *did* puts the event in the past, and there's no way of changing it. Because he didn't put his name in, he can't be in the competition.

Comment: To me, “have not done” sounds like “have not done yet” too, but I thought I was only one who thought so.

Comment: That's one of the uses of the present perfect, yeah! Compare *I did not go to Kenya* (there was an opportunity to go, but I didn't take it) versus *I have not been to Kenya* (at the current moment, that is not one of my life's experiences)